# php - select option value not passed to post

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im pretty stuck at this code, I really can't see why it should not work, i don't know if some javascript code im running beforehand is interfering?

Only showing relevant part of the code

The first section with javascript updates page when selecting another dropdown, and is placed before the code that im struggling with:
`

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

function changeDropDown(){
   var elLocation = document.getElementById('form_location_id');
   var location = elLocation.options[elLocation.selectedIndex].value;

     document.getElementById("form1").action = "choose.php?id=" + location;
     document.getElementById("form1").submit();
   }

</script>

<form id="form1" name="form1"  method="post">
<select size="1" name="form_location_id" id="form_location_id" onchange='changeDropDown(this);'>

<?php
if ($chosen_id == "1") { ?>
<option value = "1" selected><?php echo "dropdown text" ?></option>
<? } else { ?> 
<option value = "1"><?php echo "dropdown text" ?></option>
<?php } ?>

</select>
</form>

<form method="post" action="update.php">
<select size="1" id="choice" name="value">

<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

$id = $row['id'];
$number = $row['number'];
>?    
<option value = "<?php echo ($id) ?>"><?php echo "ID=" . ($id) . " - #" . ($number) . ""?></option>

<?php
}
mysqli_close($db_conn);

?>
</select>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

update.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$chosen_id = $_POST['id']; 
}
?>
`
```

I've only posted the code handling the select option and the post part...

Why is the $chosen_id variable always 0 ?
The while loop works, and fill's the variable, as this is tested with echo command inside the option line

Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: What do you see for `$_POST['submit']`?

Comment: That variable is passed, strange enought... value is "Submit" as it should

Comment: your php closing tag seems wront at '>? '

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST['id']` and `<select size="1" id="choice" name="value">`

Use `$_POST['value']`

Comment: nope, still no value parsed, i've done this so many times before, but not together with that javasript on the same page, I really dont know why it's not working...

Comment: @BulletEyeDK, can you explain, what do you want? I see GET-parameter "id" and POST-parameters "value" and "form_location_id". Which of them do you need?

Comment: the javascript refreshes page when a top dropdown menu changes, that's the id used by get... it then loads the refreshed page with that id... and changes the content in the bottom dropdown where i have the code mentioned... the problem is parsing the lower dropdown variable to another page with submit and post

Comment: I only added the java script code, as I figure this can be the problem not parsing the variable, but im not sure... All code works, just not gathering the submitted variable with post after submitting

Comment: You can check in browser developer's tools post-data which browser sends to server.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the wrong key 
if you trying to get the value of `form_location_id`

```
$chosen_id = $_POST['form_location_id'];
```

And if you trying to get the value of `choice`

```
$chosen_id = $_POST['value'];
```

This is why when you post a form to php it use html name attribute as key to assign the value to $_POST Array

Comment: form_location_id is actually the variable value used in the javascript, so it's not the variable im trying to get...

Comment: That's why i put choice there too as there were two select tags. :)

Comment: ahh ofcourse :) - but this still does not get the variable... I think it must be the fact that im having 2 <form></form> on the page, one working with the javascript, and one handling the submit, the forms are named different, and so is the variables, so this should not give any problems, but it really cant be any other thing i suppose..., thanks for you help until now.

Comment: oh yeah i missed that.. you are submitting form1 as in your JS but the select you need is in other form that's why data is not getting post. Programming can be this much fun :) hope you get this solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change Update.php to

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
$chosen_id = $_POST['value']; 
}
?>
```

Comment: still an empty variable

Comment: Ok, I wonder if you are chosing an option before submitting the form. Could it be that the select element's value is empty like `' '` ?

Comment: As mentioned in another comment, that closing php tag might also be a problem. Look in the second form.

Comment: i've made an echo in that select option statement, where the actual ID that im trying to pass is showing in the dropdown menu, so i guess the value is there, it's just not passed, i reckon you mean this : <option value = "<php echo ($id) ?>"><php echo "ID= " . ($id) . "" ?>/option>

Comment: I'm actually referring to how you close php in like this: `<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$number = $row['number'];
>?`

that last part might be causing issues.

And in refrences to that option tag. I just noticed it looks like you are trying to add a space at the end. Here's how I'd do that:

`<option value = "<?php echo ($id) ?>"><?php echo "ID=" . ($id) . " - #" . ($number) . " "?></option>`

Comment: thanks for taking time to go through my code... the space is just at type here in the code, it's not the problem... I just succeded in passing a variable through to the page after submit, done that with <input type="hidden" value = "<?php echo ($id)?> name = "test"> and that works, but unfortunally not 100% as the options are filled up inside a while loop, the hidden input line is outside of this ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `form_location_id` to get the required value. You are using the wrong key to access the data. You need to use the name of the input. In this case, the input is the `select` and the name of that is `form_location_id`. So,  you need to do this.

```
$value = $_POST['form_location_id'];
```

Try it out and do let me know if it worked out for you.

Comment: nope, did not work, this "form_location_id" is in another <form> </form> before the one im trying to get data from, thanks for help anyways ;)

Comment: O i see now. If its the other one then you need to use `$_POST['value']`  i believe. And even if this is not working, then try to check the HTML in the browser that was generated in the php, you might get some clue about what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone posting idea's - i've actually got it working, the code was actually working, only error was a misplaced  tag, which was placed inside a  tag, when placed outside this tag it works ;)